# Magnetization derivation for non-Ising systems

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-spin, spin-models

Can anyone help get me started on deriving a more general magnetization for non-Ising systems? I cannot find any information on a general derivation of the magnetization of 1D, 2D, or 3D systems of Heisenberg spin arrays. I'd like to explore systems with spin moments larger than 1/2.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "more general magnetization"? Magnetization $\hat{\vec{M}}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i \hat{\vec{S}}_i$ is defined as the average over all spins on the lattice. Is it that you want to write down a model in which $\hat{\vec{S}}$ is not written in terms of basis vectors of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, but the basis of $\mathrm{SU}(N)$?